# Pesquisa sobre interesse em novas tecnologias

Tags: debate, pesquisa

Estou participando do início de um projeto da faculdade e gostaria de um apoio de vocês.

A ideia inicial é explorarmos um pouco essa questão de como nós da computação estudamos coisas novas.

Eu venho vos pedir para que [respondam as questões dessa pesquisa](https://goo.gl/forms/PCOZ9nHHnsiQRz5g1). São apenas 9 perguntas bem simples e a maioria é objetiva.

Comment: Gostei da pesquisa, mas dê uma revisada na redação de algumas questões. Por exemplo: "*Se você disponibilizado hoje, materiais curtos e de qualidade, em português, para aprender Kotlin, qual a probabilidade de você se interessar?*"

Comment: @VictorStafusa Obrigadão pelo retorno. Eu cheguei a ver isso e mandei pro pessoal, ainda não tenho acesso a edição.

Comment: @LINQ respondi as questões ;)

Comment: @LINQ vc vai compartilhar o resultado com a comunidade?

Comment: @gato Postarei aqui nesse mesmo post.

Comment: Terceira pergunta: *Você se sente confortável tendo aprender alguma nova*, faltou um **que**

Comment: Além de ser dificílima de estimar, na minha opinião (visto que varia muito conforme a época), a pergunta sobre tempo de estudo deveria permitir outras métricas (h por semana, mês). Eu mesma respondi em h por semana.

Comment: Respondido com sucesso!! Thks :)

Comment: A pergunta sobre se conhece Kotlin é sacana, pois respondi "Não", mas um minuto depois já é "Já ouvi falar" e talvez algumas horas depois já seja "Sim" =D. O que é pretendido com essa pesquisa? Pois sempre que respondo uma pesquisa imagino, qual tipo de informação ou tomada de decisão é pretendida com o resultado da mesma!

Comment: @Fernando A ideia é que fomentemos um movimento de criação de conteúdo. Pretendemos tanto incentivar nossos colegas a estudarem fora do horário de curso, como àqueles que detém algum conhecimento que ensinem o que sabem da forma que for. Ainda não temos diretivas básicas de **o que** e/ou como vamos fazer isso. É um pontapé inicial, queremos saber o que "o nosso pessoal" pensa sobre. A pergunta sobre Kotlin foi só um exemplo de algo que está sendo bastante falado (pelo menos por nós) e por isso fizemos as perguntas.

Comment: Não fui eu quem deu downvote :P

Comment: Eu imagino que não, @GuilhermeNascimento. Não entendo o porquê dos _downvotes_. Sinceramente, eu gostaria de entender.

Comment: @LINQ também não sei a motivação, MAS presumo que seja devido ao tipo de assunto, não é um problema específico na sua pergunta, deve ser sobre o tipo de pergunta. NÃO estou afirmando, só estou presumindo.

Comment: Não entendi, diz problema específico do site?

Comment: @LINQ não, editei o comentário, veja se consegue entender